# Detecting a significant change in the difference between two rates from T1 to T2

Tags: confidence-interval, count-data, pre-post-comparison

I asked this previously but I failed to activate my account so I was not able to respond to comments and my question was never answered.  Here is attempt 2:

I have two rates of compliance for two different populations:

```
 Group      N         Compliant     Rate (Compliant/N)
   A       696          155             22.27%
   B       1058         442             41.78%
```

Assuming these responses conform to a Poisson distribution and the N-s do not change between time 1 and time 2, I want to know how to determine the amount of change in the difference score that is needed for that change to be considered statistically significant. So if the difference at the current time (T1) is 19.51%, what is the magnitude of the change needed to reach statistical significance at T2?

Comment: These data wouldn't be Poisson, if you have a known total who could be compliant. Instead they would be binomial. Are you wanting to compare A vs B, or T1 vs T2, or both? Are you essentially trying to do a power analysis?

Comment: Please merge your accounts, Scott.  The link is at http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts. You did not respond to the comments and questions to [your original question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110749), so please respond to them here.

Comment: Thanks for the replay gung.  I'm trying to figure out the change needed to make the difference between the T1 rate difference and the T2 rate difference significant.  Its kind of like a power analysis but rather than trying to figure out sample size based on effect size, I'm trying to figure out effect size based on sample size.